# Cannot pass indexpath from collectionView (into LightBox package )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gallery

I installed this package  https://github.com/hyperoslo/Lightbox ,but I do not know how to pass the index of my collectionView to display the desired picture , not the first one

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller = LightboxController(images: imagess)
    controller.pageDelegate = self as? LightboxControllerPageDelegate
    controller.dismissalDelegate = self as? LightboxControllerDismissalDelegate
    controller.dynamicBackground = true
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In this case, I can change pictures but the first one always appears

I seem to have read everything but I did not find this important detail.

If i do like this :

```
let controller = LightboxController(images: [imagess[indexPath.row]])
```

I can only view one picture with the desired index but cannot change picture in gallery

Help pls :-)

Comment: can you please show 'imagess' array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set start index to see the current image;

so try this;

```
let controller = LightboxController(images: imagess, startIndex:indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Thanks) remember it